# SVG not fill correctly displays when you change background-color

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

When the dark pouring my svg displayed not correctly - at the edges of black or white blotches, but on a white background or a larger size everything is OK. Why so? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rd2d2/g7y8hr11/1/)

```
<div class="svg-wrap">
<img src="http://imgh.us/star_1.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be chrome specific for anyone looking.

Comment: I can not understand what you mean.

Comment: Looks the same in Chrome. IE11 & FF to me

Comment: looks fine to me too Chrome 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit) OS X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little hacky but this renders as normal for me in chrome when I apply a scale transform on the svg ([see result](http://jsfiddle.net/g7y8hr11/13/)).

```
transform: scale(1.00001, 1.00001);
```

Here's a comparison for those that can't replicate:
[image]

This was in Chrome 41.0.2272.101 (64-bit) Windows 8.1.

Comment: if you zoom out in the browser the problem return)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of anything that fixes the zoom issue.